# Runtime complexity of a counting function

Tags: python, list, complexity-theory

```
def findTarget(myList, target):

    count = 0

    for item in myList:

         if (target == item):

              count = count + 1

    return count
```

I was told this is 0(log)n 
although i believe this is 0(1) ? can someone confirm or deny?

Comment: Why do you believe this runs in constant time? ***O*** ( *n* )

Comment: Write relevant titles in the future.

Comment: Given your current question, we can only tell you that you are wrong. If you could explain why you believe this runs in O(1) time, we could tell you _why_ you are wrong, which would be more helpful to you and to others reading this site.

Answer (score 7):

Your loop has `N` compares and less than `N` additions -- leading to a maximum of 2*N operations which gives you an O(N) algorithm.

Note that for lists, this is a builtin method:

```
myList.count(item)
```

which will push the loop into `C` code -- It's still O(N), but I bet that version will run a bunch faster than your version :).

Answer (score 2):

The loop is `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of `myList`.